# Automatic input in web tool and save the output files using Python

Tags: python, web-crawler, webautomation

Here is a web-based tool for some chemical computation [link here](http://www.aim.env.uea.ac.uk/aim/model2/model2b.php).

1. Entering the data in the input box as follows, then enter "run", a data report can be exported. 
   [image: input example]

   For example, relative humidity: 0.45, H+: 0.2, SO42-: 1.1, NH4+: 3, NO3-: 1

---

2. Saving the output data table

   The generated table shown like follows is what I want to acquire.

   [image]

---

Since I have a lot of dataset as the input data， is there any method to import those data, and save the output results.

Any advice or tutorial would be appreciated.

Comment: Beautifulsoup is only a parser, it won't send data to any input fields. Try Selenium https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/

Comment: Thanks for your editing and kind suggestion!